# Updating a field on Account level, from field on Contact

Tags: workflow, contact, update, roll-up-summary

This *sounds* like it should be super simple; and I can't believe I can't find documentation to support my assumption. I have a field, MDID (managed department ID) on the contact level, and I'd like that same value ported over to the same named field on the account level. I thought I'd be able to do something simple like a workflow rule and field update, but doesn't look like it. Should I be looking at the Process Builder or is there perhaps a simpler option.

Comment: And what behavior do you want for multiple child records? Save the most recent value? Concatenate all of them together?

Comment: In _theory_, that MDID value is going to be the same for **any** contact on an account. That value is being passed from our user chat application, to a custom field on the lead, and mapped to a custom field on the contact, when said lead is converted to a contact. Does that make sense? The number, the MDID, is essentially an "account number".

Answer (score 1):

Workflow rules can only affect the currently processed record. However, the Process Builder can indeed update a related record. When you create the Process Builder, start with "When a record is modified", choose "Contact" as the primary object, and choose to perform an immediate update on the related Account.

Answer (score 0):

If Managed Department ID is the same for all contacts in an account, then you should use a cross-object formula field in Contact to reference the account's MD ID.  That's the point of using a relational database; the child can inherit the parent's values.

To get a value into the Account MD ID field, you can make a conversion mapping of the Lead MD ID field to the Account MD ID field.

Comment: Hey David- Thanks for the reply! If I understand your suggestion, you're saying I can have the child inherit the parent's value. Isn't the "contact" the child and account is the parent? If so, I need it to go the other way; the contact has the value and I need _that_ value to be copied up to the account level.

Comment: If MD ID acts like "account number" then it should be managed at the account level, not the contact level.   Think of it like the account name field -- would you fill in the account name field on the contact record and then update the account, and then update all the other contacts with the account name?

Comment: Oh I totally agree! I just don't have a way to get this value, the MDID, automatically to the account level. I only have Intercom (our client chat app that grabs certain attributes,) to SFDC contact/lead level syncing. So Intercom can grab that value, the MDID, and map it to a field on the contact/lead object. That's why I need to surface it from the contact to the account level. Intercom, where this MDID is being grabbed from, doesn't populate to the account level.

Comment: Are you converting all leads to contacts?  Or is the chat integration updating contacts directly as well?

Comment: Not all leads become contacts; the chat application will only create leads I believe, as opposed to creating contacts.